# Go to first link in list with tab if button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a header and a toggable menu where I want the focus to go from the menu button to the first link in the menu, when the button is clicked. Because of the design/structure the menu button and the menu cannot be next to eachother. The menu consist of a list with a listitem of a link and a button. But I have some trouble to get it to work. What I basically want is the natural way of navigate to a menu with the tab key, even if the button and menu cannot be next to eachother.

This is my js:

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const list = document.querySelector(".list");

button.addEventListener("click", this.setFocus.bind(this));

function setFocus(e) {
  if(list.classList.contains("show")) {
     if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        list.querySelector("a").focus();
     }
  }
}
```

And a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pistevw/7opwkd3c/)

Comment: In what way is the question unclear?

Comment: To me the desired outcome is not clear. May you describe it better?

Comment: What do you mean with "focus"? Do you want to click on "Menu" and go to the first link through its anchor?

Comment: If I click on "Menu", the menu is toggled (open), then I want the focus to be on the first link in the menu when I press tab key.

Comment: Why are you checking for a `keyCode` on a click event?

Comment: Because I want the focus to be on the menu only when the menu button is clicked (the menu is visible). But that's maybe unnecessary?

Comment: The problem is that you're adding a "click" event listener checking AT SAME TIME if the TAB button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `if (e.keyCode == 9)` check, your code will work as expected.

By default, in most browsers the `focus` effect won't display a visual effect on all elements unless it's applied by the keyboard, so in this example I have added a red background to highlight what's happening.

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const list = document.querySelector(".list");

button.addEventListener("click", this.setFocus.bind(this));

function setFocus(e) {
  if (list.classList.contains("show")) {
    list.querySelector("a").focus();
  }
}
```

```css
:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Menu</button>
<a href="#">Another link</a>

<ul class="list show">
  <li class="li">
    <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
    <button class="button">chevron</button>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
    <button class="button">chevron</button>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <a class="link" href="#">Link</a>
    <button class="button">chevron</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want a visual effect in this case, you could apply a style to `.link:focus` (Chrome uses something along the lines of `outline: #000 1px;`)

Comment: Okey, I understand that, thank you! But what I tried to accomplish with the key check was that I want the focus to be on the menu after the tab is pressed. When  you navigate with only the keyboard, then you tab to the menu button, open the menu and then tab to the first menuitem.

Comment: @pistevw If you press enter on the button, it should still swap the focus for you. Do you mean you want to open the sub-menu when the first button gains focus? If so, you could also listen for the focus event: `button.addEventListener("focus", this.setFocus.bind(this));`

Comment: What I want is to be able to navigate from the menu button to the menu with the keyboard. So, when I open the menu with, for instance space key, and after that press the tab key', I want the focus to go to the first menu link. I'm sorry if I explain in a complicated way.

Comment: Hmm, well, what's already in the answer should do that. One thing that might be a problem is if you have code that is applying the `.show` class that you've not included in the question. If `setFocus()` runs before `show` is applied, it won't work.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle so that the menu is displayed when I click the button, but right now the focus goes straight to the menu link when I open the menu. I want the focus to go to the menu link after the menu is opened. So: Open menu, then tab to menu link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to tab through the links without focussing on the buttons? In which case, you can set the `tabindex` of the buttons to -1. This prevents them being in focus when tabbing through the elements.

```
<button class="button" tabindex="-1">chevron</button>
```

Also, you are mixing your events. The event is 'click' and you are checking for a tab press. Just get rid of that check to auto focus on the first element.

```
function setFocus(e) {
  if(list.classList.contains("show")) {
    list.querySelector("a").focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: The chevrons are buttons that opens submenus so they need to be focusable. If I remove the check for keypress, when I tab from the menu button, the first chevron is focused and not the first link. Why is that?

Comment: It is because the code sets the focus on the first link in the list. Pressing tab then moves the focus to the next element which is the chevron button. Adding the check for keypress breaks the logic so the function doesn't work and never sets the focus. The focus remains on the menu button and pressing tab goes to the next element, which is the "another link" anchor. This is exactly the same as removing the click handler altogether.

Comment: I kind of understand that. But how can I put the focus on the link and not the chevron, I'm trying to do a reverse focus when I press shift+tab then put focus back on menu button. If I write `anotherLink.focus();` the menu button gets focus but not if I write `menuButton.focus();` Is it possible that you could explain how I can achieve it the right way?

Comment: It is actually already focussed on the link. Try it using external links rather than `#` to make it clearer what is happening. Click the menu button, then press enter. You will be navigated to the URL of the first link. I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npx4rLqj/

Comment: I think your problem is with your styles, so you can't see what is focussed and what isn't. Have a look at this fiddle instead, with some ugly CSS added to highlight the focussed link. https://jsfiddle.net/npx4rLqj/1/

Comment: What was the problem with my code (not exactly the code in the fiddle) was that I forgot to `preventDefault` the function when I tab from the menu button in to the menu. So your answer was correct, The first link was focused but then the tabbing moves focus to the next element (the chevron). Thank you for your answers!